# Define a cardinal successor

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

[image]

On Wikipedia, it says using the von Neumann cardinal assignment and the axiom of choice (AC) we can define the successor cardinal. But how exactly is this done?

I see that the von Neumann cardinal assignment is just defining what cardinality is.
[image]

But I don't understand the argument here, why using the axiom of replacement, we see the class of ordinals is well-ordered.

And from here, do we just apply the axiom of choice to define the cardinal successor?

Thanks!

Comment: The axiom of choice is totally unnecessary there, and I don't know why they mention it. (The axiom of choice is required to show that every set either injects into $\kappa$ or has $\kappa^+$ inject into it, but that's different.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: It reads to me like they are using AC to say that there exists an ordinal whose cardinality is greater than $\kappa$ since $P(\kappa)$ can be well-ordered, so then you can take the least such ordinal.  Of course this use of AC can be avoided.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I think that you’re right, though they certainly didn’t make that clear. The Hartogs number is briefly mentioned at the very end of the article, however, as a way to define the successor of a non-well-orderable cardinal.

Comment: @EricWofsey In that case, that strikes me as very poorly written: it reads to me as implicitly claiming that choice is necessary.